# ANSIBLE - including variables

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to load variables from file in Ansible. I run the ansible from a script

```
./run.sh desupap1 idp1 1
```

The script creates a file `~/ansible/roles/esup/vars/vars.yml` containing variable

```
vars:
  idp_rga: false
```

depending on $3 parameter.
I'm trying to load the variable for a certain group of host in a task file `/home/run/ansible/roles/esup/tasks/main.yml`

```
- name: "Sourcing esup variables"
  include_vars:
    dir: '/home/run/ansible/roles/esup/vars'

- name: "DEBUG"
  debug: var=idp_rga
```

HOWEVER the result is:

```
    TASK [esup : Sourcing common variables] ***************************************************************************
task path: /home/run/ansible/roles/esup/tasks/main.yml:1
ok: [desupap1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "vars": {
            "idp_rga": true
        }
    }, 
    "ansible_included_var_files": [
        "/home/run/ansible/roles/esup/vars/vars.yml"
    ], 
    "changed": false
}

TASK [esup : DEBUG] ***********************************************************************************************
task path: /home/run/ansible/roles/esup/tasks/main.yml:5
ok: [desupap1] => {
    "idp_rga": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [esup : Sourcing .bashrc and running start_udp_proxy] ********************************************************
task path: /home/run/ansible/roles/esup/tasks/main.yml:8
fatal: [desupap1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'idp_rga' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (idp_rga): 'idp_rga' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/run/ansible/roles/esup/tasks/main.yml': line 8, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: \"Sourcing .bashrc and running start_udp_proxy\"\n  ^ here\n"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/run/ansible/playbook.retry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `vars:` from `~/ansible/roles/esup/vars/vars.yml`. All it should contain is:

```
idp_rga: false
```

---

Otherwise you try to define a dictionary named `vars`, not a variable `idp_rga`.

<sup>And as `vars` is already a reserved word, you could access the variable in question only through `vars.vars.idp_rga`</sup>